# CSS and selecting last td

Tags: css, detailsview

Summary: Every field rows of detailsview have 2 td and their first td can apply left border. But second one (so the rightest cell of field tr(row)) couldn't applied. Even i tried

```
.dvRowEven td:nth-last-child(even)
```

or

```
.dvRowOdd td:last-of-type
```

*Now my full message:*

I am trying to write css for DetailsView (asp.net control).

I finished the header and footer. The first td cell (using them for labeling) has 1px solid border (with background image) but next td cell (using for placing controls like textbox, dropdownlist etc.) couldn't applied with same image with:

```
.dvRowEven td:nth-last-child(even)
{
    border-right: solid 1px #B4B4B2;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;

    background-position:right top;
    background-image: url('../images/dv/tdLeftBorder.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
.dvRowOdd td:last-of-type
{
    border-right: solid 1px #B4B4B2;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;

    background-position:right top;
    background-image: url('../images/dv/tdLeftBorder.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-color:Yellow;
}
```

css style. I've added whole style.

```
body
{
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('../images/bkg_topleft.jpg');
    background-position: left top;
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
    background-color: #f8f7f2;
    text-align: left;
}
.dv
{
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    text-align: left;
    background-image: url('../images/dv/dvAll.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    -moz-border-radius: 75px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.dvHeader
{
    /*---------- HEADER ---------------*/
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.dvHeaderLeft
{
    float: left;
    width: 8px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('../images/dv/headerLeft_50.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.dvHeaderCenter
{
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-indent: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.dvHeaderRight
{
    float: right;
    width: 8px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('../images/dv/headerRight_50.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: top; /*---------- BİTTİ HEADER ---------------*/
}
.dvCommandRow td
{
    border-right: solid 1px #B4B4B2;
    border-left: solid 1px #B4B4B2;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 5px;
    background-image: url('../images/dv/tdLeftBorder.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
.dvCommandRow td a
{
    color: #3e6d8e;
    background-color: #e0eaf1;
    border: 1px solid #7f9fb6;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 0pt;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 2.2;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dvCommandRow td a:hover
{
    background-color: #3e6d8e;
    color: #e0eaf1;
    border: 1px solid #33ccff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dvFooter
{
    /*---------- FOOTER ---------------*/
    background-image: url('../images/dv/dvFooterCenter.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: left top;
    border: 0;
    height: 6px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.dvFooterLeft
{
    float: left;
    width: 8px;
    height: 6px;
    background-image: url('../images/dv/dvFooterLeft.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    background-color: Transparent;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.dvFooterCenter
{
    float: left;
    height: 6px;
    background-image: url('../images/dv/dvFooterCenter.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.dvFooterRight
{
    float: right;
    width: 8px;
    height: 6px;
    background-image: url('../images/dv/dvFooterRight.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: top; /*---------- BİTTİ FOOTER ---------------*/
}
.dvEmptyDataRow
{
    border-right: solid 1px #B4B4B2;
}
.dvRowEven td:nth-last-child(even)
{
    border-right: solid 1px #B4B4B2;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;

    background-position:right top;
    background-image: url('../images/dv/tdLeftBorder.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
.dvRowOdd td:last-of-type
{
    border-right: solid 1px #B4B4B2;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;

    background-position:right top;
    background-image: url('../images/dv/tdLeftBorder.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-color:Yellow;
}
.dvField
{
    border-left: 1px solid #B4B4B2;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: right;
    background-image: url('../images/dv/tdLeftBorder.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Can you post the HTML as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for the first/last element CSS rules is flaky and not standardized across all browsers. The best compromise I've found is to add in an extra ".last" class to the CSS and stick the class in the last TD with server-side code.

Comment: Good advice but i have a lot of detailsviews and if i start to attach this .last class inside one event, i can't find time to write other codes. And its maintainence will be difficult if i want to change something about css. But really thank you.

Comment: No problem. It's really unfortunate that there's not a better way to do it (yet).